# Logstash KV plugin, convert string values to timestamp Logstash

Tags: logstash, kibana-5

I am using Logstash 5.5 to parse my logs. I have following format of the logs:

```
time taken for doing transfer once for all files in seconds=23 transfer start time= 201708030959 transfer end time = 201708030959.
```

I am using KV plugin to get the key/value pair from this file. I want to convert received "time" key's value "201708030959" to actual timestamp. I am using following configuration:

```
filter {
        kv {
                allow_duplicate_values => false
                trim_key => "\s"
                value_split => "="
        }

        date {
           match => ["time","YYYYMMddHHmm"]
        }

}
```

But, it does not convert "time" to date/timestamp when I check in Kibana. It keeps it as String. Please let me know how can I convert this string time value to actual timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

The `date` filter is used to parse a text field and use it as the timestamp for the log event.

If you take a look at your events in kibana or elastic search, as long as your date filter config is correct, you should find a field called `timestamp` of type date with the same value of your `time` string field.

If that's the case you can remove your `time` field with the `mutate` filter if you wish.

Comment: Or the [target](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-target) param can be used to set the result of the match to a particular field.